# Out of two functions, one can access variable's value, the other can't

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

The data fetched from API contains two types of elements: `cycles` which are objects of few attributes, and `last_update` object, which contains ID and `last_update: <date>`.

I'm processing them in the following way:

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      jsonData: [],
      lastUpdate: '',
      items: [
        {
          action: 'mdi-calendar',
          active: false,
          items: [{ title: '' }],
          title: 'Last Update',
        }
      ]
    }),
    methods: {
      async parseData() {
        const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5012/api/v3/cycles", {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "mode": "cors"
          }
        })
        let cycles = await response.json();
        if (cycles.length < 1) {
          console.error("Couldn't fetch cycles from DB...")
        }
        const last_update = cycles.filter(cycle => cycle.last_update);
        this.lastUpdate = last_update[0].last_update;
        console.log('Inside parseData:', this.lastUpdate);

        cycles = cycles.map(({source, revision, elements}) => ({source, revision, elements}));
        this.jsonData = cycles
      },
      setLastUpdate() {
        this.items[0].items.title = this.lastUpdate;
        console.log('Inside setLastUpdate:', this.items[0].items.title);
        console.log('Inside setLastUpdate:', this.lastUpdate);
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.parseData();
      this.setLastUpdate();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Now, the console shows the following outputs:

```
Inside setLastUpdate: <empty string>
Inside setLastUpdate: <empty string>
Inside parseData: 2023.01.24 08:44:32
```

The value gets read and updates the `lastUpdate` in `data` section. Why it can't be read by the `setLastUpdate()` function?

I was thinking that there may be something with async setting, so I made `setLastUpdate()` function async just for testing, but the asynchronous action in `parseData()` function only refers to fetching the data from API. After the data is there, all processing happens on the same set of data for both reading `cycles` and `last_update`.

How to refactor the code so that the `lastUpdate` is available for `setLastUpdate()` function and possibly update the `data.items` object?

Comment: It seems that the function `setLastUpdate` is calling before `parseData`. You need to call those functions asynchronously. You can create a single async function that will call both functions one-by-one and wait for the first to be executed. For example- `created() { this.init() }, methods: { async init() { await this.parseData(); await this.setLastUpdate();  } }`

Comment: It worked for logging the value to the console, but for some reason it doesn't update this call: `this.items[0].items.title = this.lastUpdate;`.

Comment: shouldn't it be `this.items[0].items[0].title`? Because inner `items` is an array of the objects' structure.

Comment: Indeed! Please add it as the answer and big thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per looking at the console statement, function `setLastUpdate` is calling before the `parseData` function.
So, to make the `lastUpdate` property available for `setLastUpdate`, you need to call those functions asynchronously. You can create a single async function that will call both functions one by one and wait for the first to be executed. For example-

```
created() {
  this.init();
},

methods: {
  async init() {
    await this.parseData();
    await this.setLastUpdate();
  },
},
```

One more thing-

instead of-

```
this.items[0].items.title = this.lastUpdate;
```

It should be-

```
this.items[0].items[0].title = this.lastUpdate;
```

Because inner items is having an array of objects structure.